# Update(concat) Error 1111 (HY000) - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a MySQL `UPDATE` query:

> Update(concat) Error 1111 (HY000) - Invalid use of group function

This is the query:

```
UPDATE      `oc_product_description` pd

inner join   oc_product_attribute pa
        on   pd.product_id = pa.product_id
       and   pd.language_id = pa.language_id
inner join   oc_attribute_description ad
        on   pa.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id 
       and   pa.language_id = ad.language_id
inner join   oc_product_to_category pc
        on   pc.product_id = pa.product_id

set     pd.`description`= concat(
            'Вы можете приобрести ',
            pd.name,
            ' с гарантией от производителя',
            ' ',
            max(case when ad.attribute_id=2 then ad.name end),
            ' ',
            ' ',
            max(case when ad.attribute_id=2 then pa.text end),
            ' ',
            ' и ',
            ' ',
            max(case when ad.attribute_id=3 then ad.name end),
            ' ',
            ' ',
            max(case when ad.attribute_id=3 then pa.text end),
            ' '
        )

where   pd.language_id = 4
  and   pa.attribute_id in (2,3)
  and   pc.category_id = 121
  and   pa.product_id = 102
```

This `select` query works well:

```
select   concat(
             'Вы можете приобрести "',
             pd.name,
             '" с гарантией от производителя',
             ' "',
             max(case when ad.attribute_id=2 then ad.name end),
             '" ',
             ' "',
             max(case when ad.attribute_id=2 then pa.text end),
             '" ',
             ' и ',
             ' "',
             max(case when ad.attribute_id=3 then ad.name end),
             '" ',
             ' "',
             max(case when ad.attribute_id=3 then pa.text end),
             '" '
         ) as xz

from   oc_product_description pd

inner join   oc_product_to_category pc
        on   pd.product_id = pc.product_id
inner join   oc_product_attribute pa
        on   pd.product_id = pa.product_id
       and   pd.language_id = pa.language_id
inner join   oc_attribute_description ad
        on   pa.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id
       and   pa.language_id = ad.language_id

where   pd.language_id = 4
  and   pa.attribute_id in (2,3)
  and   pc.category_id = 146

group by   pd.name
```

I think the problem is in `concat`, but why?

Comment: the problem is that you using `max` function without `group by` in your update query.

Comment: i try this. 
where pd.language_id=4
and pa.attribute_id in (2,3)
and pc.category_id = 121
and pa.product_id = 102
group by pd.name    and  have error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by pd.name' at line 22

Comment: Can you make a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for better testing?

Comment: ok. when i test i have error: DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.

Comment: Can you post the url of your sqlfiddle?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62aca6/3

Answer (score 0):

i did it!

```
UPDATE oc_product_description pd
inner join oc_product_to_category pc on pd.product_id=pc.product_id
inner join oc_product_attribute pa on pd.product_id=pa.product_id and pd.language_id=pa.language_id
SET pd.`description`=concat(
'Вы можете приобрести "', pd.name,(
select
concat( '" с гарантией от производителя',
' "', max(case when ad2.attribute_id=2 then ad2.name end), '" ',
' "', max(case when ad2.attribute_id=2 then pa2.text end), '" ',
' и ',
' "', max(case when ad2.attribute_id=3 then ad2.name end), '" ',
' "', max(case when ad2.attribute_id=3 then pa2.text end), '" ')

from oc_product_attribute pa2
inner join oc_attribute_description ad2 on pa2.attribute_id=ad2.attribute_id and pa2.language_id=ad2.language_id

where pa2.language_id=pd.language_id
and pa2.attribute_id in (2,3)
and pa2.product_id = pd.product_id
))
where
pd.language_id=4
and pa.attribute_id in (2,3)
and pc.category_id=121
and pd.product_id = 102
```